# Using turn.js in Phonegap app

Tags: cordova, css-transitions, page-curl, mobione

I want page curl effect both for iOS and Android phone.
I'm working on Mobione design center, which has a base of cordova/phonegap.

Please advise, how to use turn.js for phonegap?

```
http://www.turnjs.com/
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Did you read the Docs?

[Turn JS Documentation](http://turnjs.com/docs/Main_Page)

```
<div id="flipbook">
  <div class="hard"> Turn.js </div> 
  <div class="hard"></div>
  <div> Page 1 </div>
  <div> Page 2 </div>
  <div> Page 3 </div>
  <div> Page 4 </div>
  <div class="hard"></div>
  <div class="hard"></div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
$("#flipbook").turn({
  width: 400,
  height: 300,
  autoCenter: true
});
```

there is also a working jsfiddle ->

[JSfiddle Turn.JS](http://jsfiddle.net/blasten/A9a7E)

Comment: Yes, but I'm unable to use the same in my code, it isn't working.

Comment: You have to give us a codesnippet then...how could we guess, where your problem is? :-/

The JSFiddle works fine, so the problem is in your code.